# How to repeat file upload input box in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-input

here is my code:-

this is my script code and HTML code.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
      'action' : 'UploadFile',
      'onComplete' : function(response) {
         $('#upload').hide();
         $('#message').show();

        var statusVal = JSON.stringify(response.status);

        if(statusVal == "false")
    {
    $("#message").html("<font color='red'>"+JSON.stringify(response.message)+"</font>");
 }  
   if(statusVal == "true")
     {
    $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+JSON.stringify(response.message)+"</font>");
   }                  
},
     'onStart' : function() {
        $('#upload').show();
       $('#message').hide();
    }
   });
  });
```

this is under the body part where i have given option to upload file.

```
 <form>
<div class="centered">


     <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <div id="upload" style="display: none;">Uploading..</div>
    <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
   </form>
```

i want to add an option to upload more files in the same page using jquery or ajax?

Comment: I want to give dynamic option to add more upload file option.

Answer (score 0):

The file input can take the multiple option as documented here [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp). However be aware that it is not supported universally in older browsers.  If you are looking for something a bit more jQuery,  I have used this in the past [BlueImp](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)